# NameError: name 'col_values' is not defined

Tags: gspread

Looking at some documentation (https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/README.md and https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-lists), I see that `col_values` is listed as a method, but I keep getting errors that tell me `col_values` is undefined.

Unless for whatever reason `pip3 install gspread` didn't import the entire library, I'm unable to use `col_values`. Normally I use `import gspread`, but I also tried `from gspread import col_values`, and neither solution worked.

My guess is `col_values` is deprecated, is this the case? If so, is there any updated method we can use in lieu of `col_values`?

I'm trying to write a for loop that will read the sheet by row, perform actions based on the inputs and iterate through until there's no more data. I'm using `col_values` to assign my variables by column. Not sure if that's the most effective way to accomplish what I'm working on, but can't get past first base because of `col_values`.

Comment: Re "I'm trying to write ...", you would be far better off putting your actual *code* in the question since there may be something wrong with the way you're doing it, and it'll be easier to see that in the code rather than your description of the code. For example, it appears to be a method of the worksheet, not a top-level thing in gspread.

Comment: `col_values` is not deprecated. Agree with @paxdiablo, please share a sample of your code and an error you're getting. It'd be much easier to figure out what's going on.